# how many files changed in an svn commit under windows?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

How can I get the number of files changed on a commit, we are using tortoise svn (windows 7) but it seems that it doesn't have that functionality. Is there a way to find out how many files were changed without counting them manually?

Comment: After digging deeper in how our svn is setup, I'm told that we are using the VISUALSVN SERVER, http://www.visualsvn.com/server . Would this have something to do with not being able to see the number of paths/files changed?

Comment: From tortiseSVN no it should have no effect. That is just a tool to manage svn, it doesn't change the way svn is seen by clients. As I have said in a comment below; in tortiseSVN, I cannot see the counts that Stefan is referring to for existing commits.

Answer (score 5):

For a commit that's already done:

open the log dialog, select the revision in question. The info label right below the list of changed files shows how many paths were changed ("..., `showing XXX changed paths`").

Before you commit:
open the commit dialog. And again, look at the info label at the bottom right. It shows you how many files are shown and how many are selected for the commit.

Comment: when I open the show log dialog, in the bottom it only shows this: 
http://i.imgur.com/oW2mz.png

Comment: The before commit does show the number of files I'm about to commit though.

Comment: previous commits do not display, as you have described, in tortiseSVN on my machine. I am running 1.6.15 build 21042 64 bit.

Comment: this post has been up for over 10 days, it has been mentioned that not all versions show this information. Considering that you actually work on tortiseSVN it would be nice to know what specific version has this information.

Comment: Sorry, that info is available in the upcoming 1.7 version. You can use a nightly build if you like.

Answer (score 5):

you need to install the command line client and pipe the output from calling it into a text file:

```
svn log URL[@REV] --verbose > myLog
```

After that you can easily parse the output to count the number of files

Comment: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html there are several for windows at the bottom of the page

Comment: Alternatively you can add `--xml` option svn command line and use XML processor to count the number of modified files.

Answer (score 2):

**With TortoiseSVN:** 
1) Right Click on your working directory 
2) Select 'TortoiseSVN' 
3) Select 'Check for Modifications' (in my version of Tortoise this is the third option from the top, below 'repo-browser') 
4) The info you want is on the bottom-right (above the buttons) in the dialog that opens.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a workaround, but you won't need to install or do anything else.
Open the log and search for the exact revision number, so that only that one commit you want to see the number of changed files for is visible. Then just click on `Statistics`.
It will only show the statistics for the logs that are in the list, so only the one commit you want the the number of changed files for.
There is then the `File changes each week` which displays the number changed files (I think also the added, deleted etc.).